# Does an iOS app that uses StoreKit "use encryption", as in Apple's Export Compliance Information question?

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect, testflight

I've written a synthesiser app that uses the `StoreKit` API to interface with the App Store for the purposes of facilitating an in-app purchase.

When I uploaded the binary to App Store Connect, I was asked:

> Does your app use encryption? Select Yes even if your app only uses
> the standard encryption within Apple’s operating system.

I assume that I should answer yes because I presume that the `StoreKit` API uses encryption when it connects to the App Store.

When I answer yes, I'm asked:

> Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category
> 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?
>
> Make sure that your app meets the criteria of the exemption listed
> below. You are responsible for the proper classification of your
> product. Incorrectly classifying your app may lead to you being in
> violation of U.S. export laws and could make you subject to penalties,
> including your app being removed from the App Store.
>
> You can select Yes for this question if the encryption of your app is:
> (a) Specially designed for medical end-use
> (b) Limited to intellectual property and copyright protection
> (c) Limited to authentication, digital signature, or the decryption of data or files
> (d) Specially designed and limited for banking use or “money transactions”; or
> (e) Limited to “fixed” data compression or coding techniques
>
> You can also select Yes if your app meets the descriptions provided in
> Note 4 for Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration
> Regulations.

I don't know how I should respond to this question. Can anyone who knows something about this process offer some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that StoreKit uses encryption.

Your app qualifies for exemption (c). You just need to submit a Self-Classification Report the following January to fully qualify to use this exemption.

Comment: I wrote an article that covers when you need to report your app’s use of encryption. https://getonthestore.com/export-compliance/